# QT OpenGL is drawing my Vector to infinity

Tags: matrix, vector

I want to create a simple Cube of Lines in OpenGL and QT 5.5.
The Problem is, if I´m drawing a simple line to another Z-coordinate (from z -1.0f to z 1.0f), the line will look like it goes to z=infinity.

```
Vertex stackVerts[] = {
        {QVector3D(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f), // 0
        QVector3D(+1.0f, +0.0f, +0.0f)}, // Colour

        {QVector3D(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f), // 1
        QVector3D(+0.0f, +1.0f, +0.0f)}, // Colour

        {QVector3D(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f), // 2
        QVector3D(+0.0f, +0.0f, +1.0f)}, // Colour

        {QVector3D(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f), // 3
        QVector3D(+1.0f, +1.0f, +1.0f)}, // Colour

        {QVector3D(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f), // 4
        QVector3D(+1.0f, +0.0f, +0.0f)}, // Colour

        {QVector3D(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f), // 5
        QVector3D(+0.0f, +1.0f, +0.0f)}, // Colour

        {QVector3D(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f), // 6
        QVector3D(+0.0f, +0.0f, +1.0f)}, // Colour

        {QVector3D(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f), // 7
        QVector3D(+1.0f, +1.0f, +1.0f)}, // Colour

};
GLushort stackIndices[] = {
    0,1,
    1,3,
    3,2,
    2,0,
    0,4,
};
...
glDrawElements(GL_LINES, 10, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
```

The Matrix is set a Uniform:

```
_transMatrix.setToIdentity();
_transMatrix.perspective(60.0f, (float)(width()/height()), 0.1f, 100.0f);
_transMatrix.translate(0, 0, -3);
_transMatrix.rotate(64,0,1,0);
_program.setUniformValue("transMatrix",  _transMatrix);
```

The Vertex.glsl:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
// Set default precision to medium
precision mediump int;
precision mediump float;
#endif

attribute vec3 a_position;
attribute vec3 a_color;

uniform mat4 transMatrix;

varying vec3 theColor;
void main()
{
    vec4 v = vec4 (a_position, 1.0);
    gl_Position = v * transMatrix;
    theColor = a_color;
}
```

The GL_DEPTH_TEST is enabled and if i change the translation of z to -1000, it will still go to infinity.

[Translate z=-3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfnzs.jpg)
[Translate z=-1000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aOzt.jpg)